# Shared taxi from Abu Dhabi to Dubai

Tags: dubai, taxis, abu-dhabi, ride-sharing

Does anyone know of a shared taxi service for weekend round trips from Abu Dhabi to Dubai? Something for a daily commute from Dubai to Abu Dhabi would be helpful too. A private taxi would be AED 200-300 which is too expensive. I am aware of the E100 (Ghubaiba to Abu Dhabi) and E101 (Ibn Battuta to Abu Dhabi) RTA buses, but I would rather pay a bit more for a door-to-door shared taxi.

Comment: Door-to-door and shared taxi rarely go hand in hand.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible at the main bus stations:

> Lone passengers wanting to travel by car do have the option of a sharing taxi. At the main bus stations in Abu Dhabi and Dubai, taxi drivers offer single passengers the chance to share a taxi to the other emirate for between Dh40 and Dh60 each, depending on whether they have a four- or six-seater car.

([Source](https://www.thenational.ae/lifestyle/travel/how-to-get-from-dubai-to-abu-dhabi-taxi-bus-and-airport-shuttle-travel-information-1.859431))

I found no door-to-door shared taxi, as these rarely work together.